Is $l^p$ with $l^\infty$ metric complete?
Let $p \in [1,\infty)$, and consider $l^p$ with the $l^\infty$-metric,
$$\rho_\infty(x, y) = \sup_n |x_n - y_n|.$$
Is $(l^p, \rho_\infty)$ complete?
My suspicion is that it is not complete, so I have been trying to find an example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge in $(l^p, \rho_\infty)$. I thought perhaps the sequence $(x^{(m)})$ given by
$$x^{(m)}_n = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m} \right)^n$$
would do the trick, because it "approaches" the constant sequence $(1,1,\dots) \in l^\infty \setminus l^p$. Except I now realize it doesn't really, with respect to the $\rho_\infty$ metric. My intuition was based on more familiar metrics and mislead me.
Now I feel kind of stuck, and I wonder if my intuition is all wrong here. Maybe $(l^p, \rho_\infty)$ is complete after all?

Let us assume that the space $l^p(\Bbb N)$ is complete w.r.t. the $\sup$-norm.
Denote this space by $Y$, so explicitly $(Y,\ \|\cdot\|_Y)=(l^p(\Bbb N), \ |\cdot |_\infty)$. Denote the usual $l^p$-space by $X$, so $(X,\ \|\cdot\|_X)=(l^p(\Bbb N), \ |\cdot |_p)$.
Observe that for some $x$ in $l^p(\Bbb N)$ we have for every $n\in\Bbb N$
$$
|x_n|
=\Big(\ |x_n|^p\ \Big)^{1/p}
\le \left(\ \sum_j|x_j|^p\ \right)^{1/p}
=|x|_p\ ,
$$
and passing to $\sup$ w.r.t. $n$ we obtain
$$|x|_\infty\le |x|_p\ .
$$
This means that the application, which is the identity at set level,
$$
X\to Y\ ,\qquad x\to x\ ,
$$
is a contraction. So it is bounded (continuous). By the Banach Isomorphism Theorem the inverse is also bounded. So there is a constant $C>0$, taken to be a natural number, such that for all $x$ in $l^p(\Bbb N)$ we have
$$
|x|_p \le C |x|_\infty\ .
$$
Consider now $x$ to have finite support of the shape $(1,1,\dots,1,0,0,0,0,\dots)$, and we have to take enough ones to get a contradiction.

Thank you! I haven't studied the Banach Isomorphism Theorem yet, so I wouldn't have found this proof on my own. I wonder if there is also some simple counterexample one could cook up.

In my opinion applying the Banach theorem is an overkill. The proof can be made elementary.

I could have taken a decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ of positive numbers, $x_n\searrow0$, and truncate it. Then i have to take an explicit one. But my choice of a kind of a solution is the one i would give in an (oral) exam, an other kind of Q+A place, it immediately makes the Q-side offer questions in the next level. Else, this answer attracts the follow-up question with the $l^p$ space over some other measure space like $[0,1]$ or $\Bbb R$. (Here this is also good possible.) Also, this is the standard "application" for the theorem, and lets us ask equivalently if there is a domination of norms.

It is $l^p \subseteq c_0$ the space of null sequences. $(c_0, ||\cdot||_\infty)$ is complete so your example cannot work since $(1,1,\dots) \in l^\infty \setminus c_0$. But try another one:
For $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ let
$$x_n^{(m)} := \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}(1+\frac{1}{m})}$$
Then the sequence $x^{(m)}$ is in $l^p$ because
$$||x^{(m)}||_p^p = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |x_n^{(m)}|^p = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{m}} < \infty$$
Let $x := \left(\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then it holds $x^{(m)} \to x$ as $m \to \infty$.
For it is $|\exp(z)-1| \leq 2|z|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and thus
$$\left|x^{(m)}_n - \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\right| = \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\left|1- \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{mp}}\right| = \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\left|\exp\left(\frac{1}{mp}\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)-1\right| \leq \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\cdot 2\frac{\log(n)}{mp}.$$
Therefore since
$$\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/p}} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty$$ it is
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/p}}\right) \leq C < \infty$$
and thus
$$||x^{(m)}-x||_\infty \leq \frac{2}{mp}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/p}}\right) \leq \frac{2C}{mp} \to 0 \text{ as } m \to \infty.$$
But $x \notin l^p$ since
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |x_n|^p = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty.$$
Therefore $l^p\subseteq l^\infty$ is not closed and thus $(l^p,||\cdot||_\infty)$ not complete.

Let $$x^{(n)}_k= \begin{cases}k^{-1/p} & 1\le k\le n\\ 0&k>n\end{cases}$$ The sequence $\{x^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^\infty $ satisfies the Cauchy condition in $\ell^\infty$ as for $n>m$ we have $$\|x^{(n)}-x^{(m)}\|_\infty ={1\over (m+1)^{1/p}}$$ Assume the sequence $x^{(n)}$ is convergent to $x\in \ell^p$ with respect to $\ell^\infty $ norm. As $$|a_k-b_k|\le \|a-b\|_\infty$$the numerical sequence $x^{(n)}_k$ is convergent for every $k$ to $x_k.$ However $$\lim_nx^{(n)}_k=k^{-1/p}$$ Hence $x_k=k^{-1/p}.$ This contradicts $x\in \ell^p.$
